# What do rationals represent?

Tags: intuition, rational-numbers

While learning about the construction of number systems, I realized that I had many misunderstandings of crucial concepts which I was learning intuitively. I recently learned about the construction of the rationals as a set of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of integers (m,n), with n ≠ 0. Also I know how additon and multiplication are defined on that set. I know that the rationals exhibit good mathematical properties but what I wonder is what is their interpertation? What do they represent? For example what a half represents? Should I be content with the explanation that is given to 5 year olds about dividing pizza in half and taking one piece of them? Is there a defined real world meaning for rationals?

Comment: The rigorous mathematical definition is the set of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of integers.  The intuition is the pizza slices.

Comment: It's the one I use.  The rational numbers come about as the result of division; it seems only natural to use a thing that we usually divide to create our intuition about it.

Comment: $a/b\,$ represents the (unique) solution of $\ b\,x = a\ \ $

Comment: @Dan Uznanski I don't think you can say that the rationals come about as the result of division. They are just pairs of integers with operations defined on them and nothing else. We only think of it as division.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Yes, and that's the mathematical interpretation of it and is perfect for mathematical purposes. But what is the interpretation in the real world? I don't have problems thinking about this mathematically. My problem arises when trying to connect this to a real world situation.

Comment: In the real world, a *rational* is the result of an operation of measurement; if we measure the lenght of a stick with a graduated rod (let assume with decimal subdivision), we will find that the lenght can be expressed as $n$ "plus" $k$, where $n$ is a multiple of the "unit of measure" used and $k$ $(0 < k < 10)$ is the number decimal subdivision of the "unit". In fractional notation, the lenght of the stick will be : $(10n+k)/10$ and this is a *rational* number. Of course the decimal system of measure is absolutely "conventional" ...

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA This means that you $associate$ some meaning to the two integers that represent the pair. So, I can associate some meaning to the first integer and another meaning to the second and make the fraction something meaningful to me? Am I right?

Comment: Yes; if the measure of the lenght of the stick reports e.g. $9.5$ inches, we can rewrite it as a fraction : $95/10$. Thus, the fractional notation is a way of "managing" the subdivision of the unit ...

Comment: They are both equivallent so it doesn't matter whether one uses decimal expansion or fractions, they both represent rational number.

Comment: @J.M One real-world interpretation of fractions is linear scaling operations, e.g. $2$ and $3$ represent doubling and tripling operations, and $1/2$ and $1/3$ are their inverses, e.g. they could be scaling operations provided by software that manipulates geographical maps or CAD drawings on a computer. Then $\,1/3\,$ is the "undo" operation after a tripling ($3$x magnification). This is a *universal* representation, being the regular representation of a ring, as linear maps on its additive group.

Answer (score 2):

The rigorous mathematical definition of rational numbers is that they are equivalence classes of ordered pairs of integers $(m,n)$ with $n\neq 0$ for the equivalence relation $$(m,n)\equiv (o,p)\iff mp = no.$$

I don't really understand how you first wrote the rigorous mathematical definition of $\mathbb Q$, then asked is there a rigorous mathematical definition of rational numbers...

Another way you can look at the rational numbers is that they are, given the set of natural numbers and the operations of addition and multiplication, the smallest set containing $\mathbb N$ and satisfying all the axioms for a field (they are the "smallest field containing the natural numbers").

---

As for the real world meaning of rationals... In a strict sense of the word, no mathematical concept has a direct "meaning" in nature, but I think that generally, the natural use of fractions comes from the fact that nature itself contains them. Your example with a pie is a completely legitimate way of justifying why rationals are used in real life: it is because there exists such a thing as "half a pie."

Comment: I wanted to ask if there is some defined real world meaning for the rationals. It seems i chose the wrong words :)

Comment: @J.M Ratios? Fractions?

Answer (score 2):

I differ slightly from the other comments and answers in that I don't think the real-world meaning you gave is different from the formal meaning. Maybe we can break it into steps. What I hope is that each step can be deduced from the next.

1. Two-thirds of a pizza is what you get when you divide a pizza into three equal pieces, then take two of them.
2. Two-thirds of a pizza has the property that, given three of them, you have two pizzas altogether. This property characterizes "two-thirds of a pizza." That is, if you have some percentage of a pizza, such that when you take three, you can make exactly two whole pizzas, then you have two-thirds of a pizza.
3. "Two-thirds of a pizza" is the unique solution to the equation 3x = 2 when x is interpreted as "numbers of pizzas."
4. Whatever formal model (I am using the word "model" in its everyday sense, not its mathematical sense) you have in mind for the integers, you can extend it to a model in which all equations of the form ax = b with $a \neq 0$ have solutions by using the "equivalence class trick" that you mentioned. In that larger model, the equation $3x = 2$ has a unique solution which we call 2/3.

In summary, I wouldn't take (the equivalence class of the pair (2, 3)) to be very different from (the unique solution to $3x = 2$) which is directly linked to pizza-land when $x$ is interpreted as pizza.

Comment: How can one be sure that this model with the pizza is consistent with the mathematical definition of rationals and the properties they exhibit?